# How would I go about cropping an image automatically on the server?

Tags: php

Like at Digg.com, I want to get members' pictures cropped for an avatar use. Please show me how to do this in PHP.

Comment: Are you wanting a script that does auto-cropping (similar to the auto screenshot used by sites like YouTube) or some kind of basic graphics editor UT that allows your users to crop their profile image themselves? I think you'll need some kind of face-recognition app to make the second one happen.

Comment: I want all avatars on my site to be the same size, so I need something similar to that which you could see at Digg.com when you upload a picture for your avatar.

Comment: @Anthony, what d'you know about face detection in pictures? I wonder.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a free script that does it using either GD or Imagick (Imagick is faster so I would use that):

[Crop & Resize with JavaScript, PHP, and ImageMagick](http://mondaybynoon.com/2007/01/22/crop-resize-with-javascript-php-and-imagemagick/)

From near the top of the page linked above:

> Update: A new version of this example
>   and demonstration has been released.
>   Version 1.1 includes a GD version of
>   the script as well as a number of
>   functional improvements worth checking
>   out.

Comment: @David ImageMagick results in better quality images and is faster.

Comment: @Somebody_From_Here - see my edit. And swearing is bad, mmkay?

Comment: Thank you. I'll give that a look. Also, swearing is my middle name, but I do not believe in God. =)